# No query results for model [App\User] Error al actualizar laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy intentando actualizar la tabla usuario, que esta relacionada con la tabla persona y obtengo el sgt error `No query results for model [App\User]`

Tabla persona

```
'id', 'nombres', 'apellidos', 'cedula', 'telefono', 'celular', 'email','estado',
```

Tabla users

```
'id', 'idPersona',  'idRol', 'usuario', 'password', 'estado'
```

Con el campo 'idPersona' de la tabla user relaciono a ambas tablas

```
public function update(Request $request)    {
    try{
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
        $persona = Persona::findOrFail($user->idPersona);

        $persona->nombres = $request->nombres;
        $persona->apellidos = $request->apellidos;
        $persona->email = $request->email;  
        $persona->estado = '1';
        $persona->save();

        $user->usuario = $request->usuario;
        $user->password = bcrypt( $request->password);
        $user->estado = '1';
        $user->idRol = $request->idRol; 
        $user->save();

        DB::commit();

    } catch (Exception $e){
        DB::rollBack();
    }

}
```

el script o metodo de vue para actualizar

```
actualizarUsuario(){

axios.put('/users/actualizar',{
    'nombres': this.nombres,
    'apellidos': this.apellidos,
    'email' : this.email,
    'usuario' : this.usuario,
    'password' : this.password,
    'idRol' : this.idRol,
    'id': this.idPersona
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error ocurre cuando no existe el modelo solicitado, o en palabras más prácticas, que el id que pasas a `findOrFail()` no existe o fue eliminado.

Asegúrate que el valor de `$request->id` sea:

- Un id existente en la base de datos
- Que dicho id no haya sido eliminado (incluso con Soft Delete)

---

No sé si tenga que ver (no conozco tu proyecto) pero pareciera que estás pasando un id incorrecto al momento de hacer el put con axios:

```
'id': this.idPersona
```

Según lo que explicas, **id** y **idPersona** son dos campos distintos, por lo cual esta podría ser una pequeña confusión, teniendo en cuenta que al parecer asignas un valor que puede no existir en la columna id.

Comment: gracias!! tienes razón.. estaba pasando mal el `id`  perdí mucho tiempo con ese bendito error